# Error while performing Linear Regression in R : replacement has 19000000 rows, data has 1000000

Tags: r, linear-regression, large-data

I am trying to run a linear regression on a dataset (x_final). I have split the data into test and train, my dependent variable is YDepDelay and I have stored the independent variables as XDepDelay. I am getting this error:

> Error in `[[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, i, value = c(304L, 304L, 304L,
>   304L,  :    replacement has 19000000 rows, data has 1000000

Code:

```
# To select training data - randomly sample of 1 Million rows from x_final
indexes = sample(1:nrow(x_final), size=524735)

# Split data
library("dplyr")
set.seed(123)
train <- x_final[-indexes,]
dim(train) 
test <- x_final[indexes,]
dim(test)  

#For DepDelay

YDepDelay <- as.matrix(train$DepDelay)
XDepDelay <- as.matrix(train[, names(train) != "DepDelay"])
model_DepDelay <- lm(YDepDelay ~ XDepDelay, data= train, drop.unused.levels= TRUE)
summary(model_DepDelay)
```

Comment: In what part of the code do you get the error? Also, the `lm` part will probably give you an error, because there is no `YDepDelay` and `XDepDelay` in `data = train`.

Comment: @YannisVassiliadis Thank you for pointing out. I corrected that. Still, I am getting the same error. The error appears for fitting the regression model. > model_DepDelay <- lm(YDepDelay ~ XDepDelay , drop.unused.levels= TRUE)
Error in `[[<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, i, value = c(304L, 304L, 304L, 304L,  : 
  replacement has 19000000 rows, data has 1000000

Comment: Can you try the following: 'model_DepDelay <- lm(DepDelay ~., data = yourdataset[,indexes], drop.unused.levels = T)'. Also, try setting 'ncol' when you crate XDepDelay. Last suggestion would be to use 'which(colnames(train) != train)'. Sorry for any mistakes, I'm typing from my phone

Comment: Hi @YannisVassiliadis . Thanks for the advice. I figured out that the problem was that my data contained a lot of categorical variables which had many levels, hence I was out of computational power. I reduced that and my model ran okay. Thanks for your help :)